My teacher marked me wrong for notation and I don’t know if agree with it
I’m currently taking AP Calculus BC at my high school and today I got a test back. There’s this one question that I was marked wrong on and I don’t quite agree with it. Here’s what happened:
Question 10: Consider the closed curve in the $xy$-plane given by $x^2+2x+y^4+4y=5$.
(a) Show that $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-(x+1)}{2(y^3+1)}$.
Here’s my solution:
$\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+2x+y^4+4y)=\frac{d}{dx}(5)$
$2x+2+4y^3\frac{dy}{dx}+4\frac{dy}{dx}=0$
$\therefore \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-(x+1)}{2(y^3+1)}$
I thought my answer was completely fine, but my teacher circled the $\frac{d}{dx}$ that I put before $(x^2+2x+y^4+4y)$, put a question mark and a minus one. I then asked him why it was marked wrong and he said, “you can’t put $\frac{d}{dx}$ when there are $y$s. Is there anyone that confirm what he said? I have looked on multiple websites and have found a substantial amount of teaching material that put the total derivative operator around an implicitly defined curve to obtain $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Thanks.

To the slightly different "You can't put $d/dx$ around $a=b$, obtaining "$d/dx \ (a=b)$.", I would agree.  The notation you use here seems fine.

If "you can’t put $\frac{d}{dx}$ when there are $y$s" then you can't write $\frac{d}{dx}y$, you can't write $\frac{dy}{dx}$, and the problem has no solution. I cannot follow the teacher's logic at all. How were you "supposed" to solve this?

The Wikipedia plot summary for implicit functions has a section on implicit differentiation that seems to cover applications similar to yours. ¶ That being said, I would tread carefully here. I personally wouldn't recommend demonstrating that your teacher is wrong; rather, I might ask whether this operation is permitted in the class. It's up to the teacher if they want to open this can of worms at this time. You might ask if you can have the point back (if it's important) if you promise not to use this for now.

(It might be a good tactic, if you want to discuss it with the teacher again, not to be as blunt as I was in my previous comment. Indeed, "tread carefully.")

@DavidK: Presumably, solve the quartic for $y$ and differentiate the result. :-P

BTW, the "how were you supposed to solve this" isn't a rhetorical question. Presumably there's a "correct" answer according to the answer key. If we knew what it was, it would help us intuit something about what your teacher is thinking.

This is the notation that I would use.  I am curious as to what your teacher thinks would be a better notation.

That is total nonsense, this has been consistently used in many books and publications, no idea what your teacher is thinking. Best answer to you can NOT do X is to ask :why and so how should it be done ?

Perfect solution! Replace the teacher:)

Before everyone slams the teacher haha, is it possible that you haven't captured exactly what the teacher said? Maybe there was some nuance that we're missing. Ultimately, finding out what the prescribed solution is would go a long way toward diagnosing the issue.

To follow up, my teacher just skips showing that you are taking the derivative on the implicitly defined curve. We know the chain rule and everything, but whenever he shows work, he just goes from $x^2+2x+y^4+4y=5$ to $2x+2+4y^3\frac{dy}{dx}+4\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ writing no indication of what he did to get the next step. I respect him as an educator, but cmon.

I think in practice most people don't actually write out the step where you put $d/dx$ in front of the entire expression. The difference is we remember that this step exists. At least you have a way to avoid losing points; do what your teacher did, which also is not wrong, just less detailed.

@Moti This is not a perfect solution. You cannot take the derivative of a number on the right of the equal sign and the expression on the left is not a differentiable function of $x$. It is the Implicit Function Theorem that allows us to treat the variable $y$ as a function of $x$. This is probably the point his teacher was trying to make.

@John Douma, If y=5, than there is no y'?

@Moti What are you talking about? When you have an equation like $F(x,y)=c$, its solution set is a subset of the plane. That is not a function. You cannot take the derivative of $F$ and the derivatie of $c$ and equate them. Rather, the Implicit Function Theorem, tells us that we can consider $y$ to be a function of $x$. That is what allows us to use implicit differentiation. His teacher understands this and that's why he took the point.

Actually you need to use two partial derivatives and equate to 0. You get a system of two equations and solve for x and y. May be this would satisfy your teacher.
